# Interface builder segmented controls?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm building a toolbar that I want to look at least somewhat like Preview's. I want to create the Previous/Next buttons. The way I THINK it's done is with a segmented control, each has an image in the control. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the labels underneath. I can get ONE label centered under the whole thing, but labeling the segmented control, But I can't get a Next and a Previous label under each part of the control.

What am I missing here?

thanks.

Comment: Anyone know why I can't select a correct answer here?

Answer (score 6):

As @frédéric-blanc pointed out: the only way to achieve this is with `NSToolbarItemGroup` programmatically.

The trick is to assign both a `view` and a `subitems` array to the `NSToolbarItemGroup`.

```swift
let group = NSToolbarItemGroup(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "NavigationGroupToolbarItem"))

let itemA = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "PrevToolbarItem"))
itemA.label = "Prev"
let itemB = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "NextToolbarItem"))
itemB.label = "Next"

let segmented = NSSegmentedControl(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 40))
segmented.segmentStyle = .texturedRounded
segmented.trackingMode = .momentary
segmented.segmentCount = 2
// Don't set a label: these would appear inside the button
segmented.setImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.goLeftTemplateName)!, forSegment: 0)
segmented.setWidth(40, forSegment: 0)
segmented.setImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.goRightTemplateName)!, forSegment: 1)
segmented.setWidth(40, forSegment: 1)

// `group.label` would overwrite segment labels
group.paletteLabel = "Navigation"
group.subitems = [itemA, itemB]
group.view = segmented
```

If you want to dabble with it, see the sample app code below.

### Sample App (Updated for Swift 5.1)

[image: Sample window]

This is all you need to test this in a new macOS/Cocoa sample app:

1. In Xcode, create a new macOS project using default options (Swift, storyboards).
2. Add a new file called `WindowController.swift` and paste this code into it.
3. Set the window controller's class in interface builder to `WindowController`.

```swift
import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSToolbarDelegate {

    var _toolbar: NSToolbar!

    let toolbarItems: [[String: Any]] = [
        ["title" : "irrelevant :)", "icon": "NSPreferencesGeneral", "identifier": NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "NavigationGroupToolbarItem")],
        ["title" : "Share", "icon": NSImage.shareTemplateName, "identifier": NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "ShareToolbarItem")],
        ["title" : "Add", "icon": NSImage.addTemplateName, "identifier": NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "AddToolbarItem")]
    ]

    var toolbarTabsIdentifiers: [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {

        return toolbarItems.compactMap { $0["identifier"] as? NSToolbarItem.Identifier }

    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {

        _toolbar = NSToolbar(identifier: "TheToolbarIdentifier")
        _toolbar.allowsUserCustomization = true
        _toolbar.delegate = self
        window?.toolbar = _toolbar

    }

    func toolbar(_ toolbar: NSToolbar, itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier, willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool) -> NSToolbarItem? {

        guard let infoDictionary: [String : Any] = toolbarItems.filter({ $0["identifier"] as? NSToolbarItem.Identifier == itemIdentifier }).first
            else { return nil }

        let toolbarItem: NSToolbarItem

        if itemIdentifier == NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "NavigationGroupToolbarItem") {

            let group = NSToolbarItemGroup(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)

            let itemA = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "PrevToolbarItem"))
            itemA.label = "Prev"
            let itemB = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: "NextToolbarItem"))
            itemB.label = "Next"

            let segmented = NSSegmentedControl(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 40))
            segmented.segmentStyle = .texturedRounded
            segmented.trackingMode = .momentary
            segmented.segmentCount = 2
            // Don't set a label: these would appear inside the button
            segmented.setImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.goLeftTemplateName)!, forSegment: 0)
            segmented.setWidth(40, forSegment: 0)
            segmented.setImage(NSImage(named: NSImage.goRightTemplateName)!, forSegment: 1)
            segmented.setWidth(40, forSegment: 1)

            // `group.label` would overwrite segment labels
            group.paletteLabel = "Navigation"
            group.subitems = [itemA, itemB]
            group.view = segmented

            toolbarItem = group
        } else {
            toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: itemIdentifier.rawValue))
            toolbarItem.label = (infoDictionary["title"] as? String)!

            let iconImage = NSImage(named: (infoDictionary["icon"] as? String)!)
            let button = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
            button.title = ""
            button.image = iconImage
            button.bezelStyle = .texturedRounded
            toolbarItem.view = button
        }

        return toolbarItem
    }

    func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {

        return self.toolbarTabsIdentifiers

    }

    func toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {

        return self.toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(toolbar)

    }

    func toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {

        return self.toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(toolbar)

    }

    func toolbarWillAddItem(_ notification: Notification) {

        print("toolbarWillAddItem", (notification.userInfo?["item"] as? NSToolbarItem)?.itemIdentifier ?? "")

    }

    func toolbarDidRemoveItem(_ notification: Notification) {

        print("toolbarDidRemoveItem", (notification.userInfo?["item"] as? NSToolbarItem)?.itemIdentifier ?? "")

    }

}
```

Comment: Can this be built within the interface builder?

Comment: The grouping cannot be built with Interface Builder. But you can use IB to create the `NSSegmentedControl` as an `@IBOutlet` and reference it during the toolbar setup. There's no way around the manual creation of parts of this.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer should be the accepted one as it is the only one providing a solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks @stef for the update and switch to `NSWindowController`!

Comment: No worries. And thanks for providing the original answer! Without that I never would have figured this out. Interesting tidbit: In Apple's Numbers app, you can see individual centered labels under segmented toolbar buttons. That's what led me down the path of trying to reproduce that effect. If that's a UI design pattern they want to promote, they're certainly not making it easy to reproduce in our own applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a "hack"…  In Interface Builder (IB), I've managed to recreate the look you'd like to achieve by using, as mentioned, an NSSegmentedControl instance w/ the "Capsule" style.  But for its label, I do think it's "just" the string "Previous    Next"…  (Yep, w/ some space characters as separators :( !)

**EDIT:** The right answer can be found in the comments; i.e. from Leopard, one can use the NSToolbarItemGroup class to achieve such a result with a segmented control-based toolbar item, as illustrated by code in the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSToolbarItemGroup_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005335-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1).

(Sorry for the confusion, but as I'm new to Stack Overflow, I don't know whether it's better to remove my comments—and edit my answer—, or leave them for history purposes…)

Comment: Nope, I was wrong, as click+holding the "Previous" toolbar button in Preview only highlights the "Previous"-part of this segmented control.  Forget my previous answer, it was not such a basic "hack", I'm still investigating :) !

Comment: OK, so using F-Script Anywhere (http://www.fscript.org/), I managed to inspect the class hierarchy of Preview's "Previous/Next" toolbar item; and… it's actually built using some **private** NSToolbarItemViewer class, from which each button label is represented through a (still **private**) _NSToolbarItemViewerLabelView instance.

This won't solve your problem, but that's how Preview manages to label each segment (while the default control available in IB apparently only allows one to label the **whole** control…).

Comment: ok. well, I guess that tells me that failure IS an option... 

I'm not really that surprised. Looking at the resources in the bundle, I see separate left-capsule and right capsule images (Both selected and unselected), so I was afraid that they had done some sort of manual hack with two separate buttons that just happened to be very close to each other... dang. I'd hoped there was a clever way...

Comment: Oh, oh, once again, I was wrong; or rather, not entirely right ;) ! Look, Brian: I've found what you were looking for, I suppose, and with code too!  It's in the NSToolbarItemGroup class reference documentation, in the "Overview" section: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSToolbarItemGroup_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005335-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1.  At the very end of it, there's a note re segmented controls. HTH…

Comment: Indeed, as of Xcode Tools v3.1.3 (the latest version of Apple devtools publicly available to date), one can't visually achieve such a result—since there's no NSToolbarItemGroup control to drag from the "Library" palette of Interface Builder. I'm afraid you'll have to programmatically allocate, initialize, and configure your group before adding it to your toolbar instance…

Answer (score 1):

Brian, you may not have seen my n-th comment (sic) to my initial answer (since Stack Overflow hides them in a collapsable section when there are too many of them).  But my last comment answered your latest question (i.e. the one re your inability to build an NSToolbarItemGroup from within Interface Builder).

Now that Snow Leopard is released, I can tell you you're still not able to graphically solve your issue by dragging some control from this newer IB's palette.  Nope, your only solution is IMHO, as quoted from my Aug. 27 comment, "to programmatically allocate, initialize, and configure your group before adding it to your toolbar instance."

I hope you'll see this new answer ('cause I do think you simply didn't notice my hidden comment…). Wishing you best of luck, hoping you'll be able to solve your problem with those hints, the needed code still being in the [Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSToolbarItemGroup_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005335-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) section of the NSToolbarItemGroup class reference.